# string-to-codepoints(string) equivalent in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need to get ASCII value of character and Convert ASCII code back to character if it satisfies certain conditions.

So I came across these functions:

`string-to-codepoints(string)`

and

`codepoints-to-string((int,int,...))`

provided in XSLT 2.0 (Or Rather XPATH 2.0) But unfortunately I need to use XSLT 1.0 for this task.

So My question is

Is there any equivalent of these functions in XSLT 1.0? If not Can we design it?
Can experts here help me in that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, there are only a few ASCII characters so if you are really only interested in ASCII characters in XSLT 1.0 then create an XML file that maps the 127 ASCII characters to their ASCII value and use that with substring. `string-to-codepoints` however works with Unicode and not only ASCII, so there your mapping file would need to be rather large.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using, and in what environment? Most have a mechanism for extensions, possibly you can use this to your advantage.

Comment: Why don't you explain what exactly are you trying to accomplish, not how you think it needs to be accomplished - see: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Martin and All Sorry for delay in reply.. Was stuck in some work. I've edited question now, Can you please provide a solution

Comment: Well, to replace a single character with another you can use e.g. `translate('AAABBBCCC', 'B', 'D')` even in XPath 1.0 without any extension

Comment: @Martin I want to Use regEx in replaceAll like this: `replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\xFF]", "?");`, I believe I ca't use it in simple XSLT 1.0 right? I'll require an `java` extension.

Comment: @VedantTerkar Please post an example of the input and the expected output. Also, since you're no longer using a Java XSLT processor, which processor *are* you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Sample Input `“abc”` then output should be `?abc?` as `“` and `”` are not in ASCII range `0-127` Not I'm not talking about `"` and `"`.

I'm using `SAXON` processor.

Comment: Saxon ***is*** a Java processor.  Moreover, the current version supports XSLT 2.0, so you don't need *any* extension in order to use regex.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Can I know from which version of SAXON, it supports calling java functions from xslt? Because When I try to do so it gives me error: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The URI http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java does not identify an external Java class`.

Comment: You need to read the Saxon documentation on how to call Java from Saxon. I still don't see why you would need that, when Saxon supports regex natively.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can you give me example how saxon native regex will work for me?

Comment: See Martin Honnen's answer below.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, That Solution isn't working it throws error; I've asked different question on same:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528609/calling-java-api-from-xsl-throws-exception-the-uri-http-xml-apache-org-xslt-ja

Comment: @VedantTerkar Are you using Saxon 6.5? Why can't you use the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to replace all characters with codepoints above 255 by "?" using pure XSLT 1.0 without extensions.

Define a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="upto255">&#x9;&#xa;&#xd; !"#$%.../01234...ABC...abc...úûüýþÿ</xsl:variable>
```

whose value is a string containing all the characters in the range 0..255 that are legal in XML.

Then use the double-translate trick:

```
<xsl:variable name="above255" select="translate($input, $upto255, '')"/>
```

This variable is a string containing all the non-Latin-1 characters present in the input string. Then use the recursive template

```
<xsl:template name="pad">
   <xsl:param name="char"/>
   <xsl:param name="count"/>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count=0"/>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

to create a string of the right number of question marks:

```
<xsl:variable name="qqq">
  <xsl:call-template name="pad">
    <xsl:with-param name="char" select="'?'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="string-length($above255)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then do the substitution:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($input, $above255, $qqq)"/>
```

But of course since you are in Java there is no excuse for writing all this XSLT 1.0 code which could be replaced by a single line of code if you switched to an XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon.

Comment: Thanks for you time. I've edited my question as I can't use java extension any more. Can you please Explain Me how it works.

Comment: Specially The part `$above255` how are you calculating that

Comment: The key part of my answer was invisible because I failed to tag it as code. Disappointed that it should have taken you 6 weeks to respond.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response.. Accepting this one. You are a XSLT genius. Thanks a lot. You saved me :).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you want to perform a string replacement based on a regular expression. If you are using Java and Xalan then I think you can use e.g. `java:replaceAll($inputString, $regExpPattern, $replacementString)` to call the Java String method `replaceAll`, here is a simple example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java"
    version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="java:replaceAll('abc-123-def','\w+', '?')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs `?-?-?` for me with Xalan.

On the other hand if you are using Java then you should consider moving to Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 as that way you can use the XPath 2.0 `replace` function (`replace('abc-123-def', '\w+', '?')`) without any need for extensions.

I am not sure what that has to do with your original question about string-to-codepoints and the ASCII code of characters.