# Calling Java API from XSL throws exception "The URI http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java does not identify an external Java class"

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

I'm using `SAXON` processor for `xsl` file as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    version="1.0" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template name="printjavaDate">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="java:java.util.Date.new()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select=""/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this code isn't working for me.

It throws error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The URI http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java does not identify an external Java class
                at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.styleError(StyleElement.java:803)
```

I'm not sure why is this happening. 
I've requirement of using XSLT 1.0 only.

Can I know what is causing this error? Hope experts here will help me out.

Comment: The only possible reason I can see for a requirement to use XSLT 1.0 only is to ensure that your code is portable across XSLT processors, and if that's the requirement, then using Xalan extension functions entirely defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"` is Xalan specific, if you want to use extension functions in Saxon 6 then see http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensibility.html.

Here is an example that works for me with Saxon 6.5:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:date="java:java.util.Date">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template name="printjavaDate" match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="date:new()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```