# Create an xslt function for checking if a string contains non-ASCI characters

Tags: xslt, non-ascii-characters

i want to check via and xslt function if a string of an..17 and if a character like this fould it will be replaced with underscore _.
My problem is that i dont know how to implement with the specific set of non ASCI characters. Should i create a set of the non ASCI characters and iterate through the string? Any ideas?

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports - see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or higher you can do:

```
replace($yourString, '[^\p{IsBasic_Latin}]', '_')
```

to replace all non-ASCII characters with an underscore.

Note that this will preserve *all* ASCII characters - including non-printable control codes.

Comment: For an XSLT 1.0 solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38817745/3016153

Comment: Hey! I m using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Good. Then your question is answered, is it not?

Comment: I have a maybe stupid question hehe..what is the isBasic_Latin var?

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a Unicode block: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)